# What is wrong with this PHP file rename code?

Tags: php, image, file, rename

The following code is meant to iterate through a directory of images and rename them.

I had it working well, but what I would like to add is a 'static' token at the beginning of the file that once renamed, it will then in future ignore.

For example, let's say that we have a directory of 100 files.

The first 20 of which go by the name "image-JTzkT1RYWnCqd3m1VXYcmfZ2nhMOCCunucvRhuaR5.jpg"
The last 80 go by the name "FejVQ881qPO5t92KmItkNYpny.jpg" where this could be absolutely anything.

I would like to ignore the files that have already been renamed (denoted by the 'image-" at the beginning of the file name)

How can I do this?

```
    <?php

function crypto_rand_secure($min, $max) {
        $range = $max - $min;
        if ($range < 0) return $min; // not so random...
        $log = log($range, 2);
        $bytes = (int) ($log / 8) + 1; // length in bytes
        $bits = (int) $log + 1; // length in bits
        $filter = (int) (1 << $bits) - 1; // set all lower bits to 1
        do {
            $rnd = hexdec(bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($bytes)));
            $rnd = $rnd & $filter; // discard irrelevant bits
        } while ($rnd >= $range);
        return $min + $rnd;
}

function getToken($length){
    $token = "";
    $codeAlphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $codeAlphabet.= "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    $codeAlphabet.= "0123456789";
    for($i=0;$i<$length;$i++){
        $token .= $codeAlphabet[crypto_rand_secure(0,strlen($codeAlphabet))];
    }
    return $token;
}



 $dir = "/path/to/images";
  if ( $handle = opendir ( $dir)) {
   echo "Directory Handle = $handles<br />" ;
   echo "Files: <br />" ;
    while ( false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
     if ( $file != "." && $file != ".." ) {
      $isdir = is_dir ( $file ) ;
       if ( $isdir == "1" ) {} // if its a directory do nothing
        else {
        $file_array[] = "$file" ; // get all the file names and put them in an array
        //echo "$file<br />" ;
        } // closes else
      } // closes directory check
     } // closes while
  } // closes opendir
 //Lets go through the array
 $arr_count = count( $file_array ) ; // find out how many files we have found so we can initiliase the counter
 for ( $counter=1; $counter<$arr_count; $counter++ ) {
  echo "Array = $file_array[$counter] - " ; // tell me how many files there are
  //$new = str_replace ( "C", "CIMG", $file_array[$counter] ) ; // now create the new file name
  $new =getToken(50);
  //if (substr($file_array[$counter]), 0, 3) == "gallery_image")
    //{

    //}
    //else
    //{
    $ren = rename ( "$dir/$file_array[$counter]" , "image-$dir/$new.jpg" ) ; // now do the actual file rename
    echo "$new<br />" ; // print out the new file name
    //}

  }
 closedir ( $handle ) ;
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you're doing a lot of unnecessary work for something that *should be* quite trivial.

As far as I understand you want to get a list of the files from a directory and rename all of the ones not already pre-pended with `image-`.

You can do that with the following piece of code:

```
$dir = "/path/to/dir/"; //Trailing slash is necessary or you would have to change $dir.$newname to $dir.'/'.$newname further down the code

if(is_dir($dir)){
    $dirHandle = opendir($dir);
    while($file = readdir($dirHandle)){
        if(is_file($dir.$file) === TRUE){
            if(strpos($file, 'image-') === 0)
                continue; //Skip if the image- is apready prepended
            while(TRUE){
                $cryptname = md5(mt_rand(1,10000).$file.mt_rand(1,10000)); //Create random string
                $newname   = 'image-'.$cryptname.'.jpg';                   //Compile new file name
                if(is_file($dir.$newname) === FALSE)                       //Check file name doesn't exist
                    break;                                                   //Exit loop if it doesn't
            }
            rename($dir.$file, $dir.$newname); //Rename file with new name
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use your own function then you can the change the line:

```
$cryptname = md5(mt_rand(1,10000).$file.mt_rand(1,10000));
```

To use your function instead of `md5`. Like:

```
$cryptname = getToken(50);
```

I suggest that you should also check that the file name doesn't already exist otherwise - *unlikely as it may be* - you run the risk of overwriting files.

---

### `/images/` vs `./images/`

Firstly, when dealing with the web you have to understand that there are effectively two `root` directories.

The *web root* and the *document root*. Take the example url `http://www.mysite.com/images/myimage.jpg` as far as the *web root* is concerned the path name is `/images/myimage.jpg` however, from `php` you have yo use the *document root* which would actually be something like: `/home/mysite/pubic_html/images/myimage.jpg`

So when you type `/` in php it thinks that you mean the directory which `home` is located in.

`./images/` works because the `./` means *this directory* i.e. the one that the script/php is in.

In your case you probably have a file structure like:

```
>/
  >home
    >public_html
      >images
        image-243.jpg
        image-243.jpg
      index.php
```

So because `index.php` is in the same folder as `images`: `./images/` is equal to `/home/public_html/images/`. `/` on the other hand means the parent directory of `home` which has no images folder let alone the one you're targeting.

If you're more used to windows think of it like this: in php `/` means the document root directory (on windows that would be something like `C:\`).

Comment: The code doesn't work as it stands? I can't find the error either.

Comment: What did you type in as `$dir`?

Comment: `/images/` as all the images are stored in a sibling directory.

Comment: I have used `./images/` now, and that works well... Why though? Could you explain. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, I have added an _explanation_ above... Sorry if it's jumbled! Just ask if there's anything you don't understand :) Also, you might want to try this: `echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to see the file structure of your site... It might help your understanding

Comment: THANK YOU! In all the tutorials I have looked at over the years not one has explained that let at all, let alone that well. That makes complete sense.

Comment: No problem :) Glad you found it useful!

Answer (score 0):

You have the 'image-' in front of the directory portion of your file name:

```
$ren = rename ( "$dir/$file_array[$counter]" , "image-$dir/$new.jpg" )
```

should be

```
$ren = rename ( "$dir/$file_array[$counter]" , "$dir/image-$new.jpg" )
```

Comment: Maybe not, OP really has an image-[DIR] directory